# WPF Application Front end Back end

Tags: wpf

I am looking for some advise/direction to go in with the redesign of the core application that we offer.   I am looking to build a WPF application that we host through a Citrix Xenapp Server.  This Application is a customized database for holding records.  I would like for this to be split into two different parts, but both would run for the server.  The front end would be the same for all of the clients, which each have multiple users, the back end would hold the specific documents that that client would be filling out.  I want these separate so that I could update each of them independently.

Any information or links to something similar would be appreciated.

Comment: Is Citrix XenApp a remote desktop technology? WPF does not work well over remote desktop, because it sends graphics (as opposed to tokens sent by Winforms, for example) over the wire. Before you make any decision talk to Citrix to see if they recommend using WPF together with their technology

Comment: @HighCore I have a WPF application hosted on Citrix.  The WPF version works better than the prior Winforms version.

Comment: Wow... that IS good news.. I keep telling everyone that WPF is way better than anything else currently in existence (when it comes to UI frameworks) and they keep bashing at me saying winforms is 'simpler' hence it is 'faster'. I just never used it over rdp technologies such as citrix to confirm. then you're ready to go..

Comment: @HighCore clearly running on the desktop is more responsive.  But I think WPF on Citrix does better than WinForms on Citrix.  We don't run Aero.  And in design do stuff like not show content while resizing.

Comment: WinForms probably operates at a slightly lower level than WPF, because you're effectively dealing directly with HWND objects. Any resulting difference in performance is mostly undetectable though so in my view WPF wins in most contexts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the WPF client connect to a WCF service.

[What Is Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

Tired of debating HighCore so let me expand on MY answer.

This is exactly what I do in a commercial application.   Client on Citrix as for security it is required that we host the client.  Host the service in WCF.  For production the service is on a separate box but for test the service is on the same box.

The service approach lets you update separately and then just point to the new endpoint.  You can even test out a new client against the current production endpoint and then roll the new client to production.

You can pass different parameters to the same back end or have different back ends.  We have both.

Comment: Im not sure he really needs that, he's stating that the client side of the application and the server side will effectively live in the same machine. Why would he want to add complexity by adding a service layer?

Comment: @HighCore If you have a way that you prefer for hosting a client with a configurable server then post it.  This is a model I like and I don't find a service model complex and lots of options to tune a service model.

Comment: the original question did not state that 'having a client with a configurable server' was a requirement. If the client and server will live in the same process in the same machine, the 'service layer' would be just an extra DLL in the project with no need for WCF service endpoints or IIS or anything like that.

Comment: I do understand what WCF is for and how it works, I actually use it in my products. I did not say having a service model was complex, I said it adds unneeded complexity to a simple non-networking application. This is a fact.

Comment: By complexity I mean having to declare the service contracts and potientially having to add service references in the client side. Then the WCF services have to be hosted somewhere as well, which is yet another unneeded thing in this case.

Comment: @Blam The reason that I want the split because we will use this application for many different clients.  I want the front end to be the same for all of my clients and want to be able to update it separately from the back ends.  This application will store forms/documents.  Each client will have different forms/documents in their back end but the same front end to access them.  The reason i used the terms front end/back end is that I didn't want them to get confused with client/server.  I am hoping the link provided will give me what I am looking for

Comment: @HighCore The reason that I want the split because we will use this application for many different clients.  I want the front end to be the same for all of my clients and want to be able to update it separately from the back ends.  This application will store forms/documents.  Each client will have different forms/documents in their back end but the same front end to access them.  The reason i used the terms front end/back end is that I didn't want them to get confused with client/server.  I am hoping the link provided will give me what I am looking for

Comment: Even if using WCF... there's many situations where an update to the frontend or backend layers of an application also forces an update in the other layer. For example if your datamodel / common layer changes, or if the interfaces (service contracts) between them changes. I don't think it is a good idea to maintain different versions/build in production servers (such as updating the client but not the server). This is only applicable to small cosmetic changes or minor bug fixes, but surely daily maint. of an application requires all layers to be rebuilt / published.

Comment: Also, if you will use WCF there's no reason to use Citrix anymore.. you could provide an installable version of the client application to your users (which will improve usability by removing the remote desktop thing) and have it WCF back to the server thru internet. That's what we did here and it works great.

Comment: @HighCore Again if you have a better architecture then post your own answer.  Really.  How can you assert there is NO reason to use Citrix.  You don't know there is not a reason to have a client on Citrix.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, users might (I said MIGHT) be able to install the client part of the software, and then WCF can be used over the internet to get to the server, which is a different approach as opposed to RDP to the application, which makes the UX poorer.

Comment: No you said "there's no reason to use Citrix anymore".  Please, for the third time if you think there is a better approach then post your OWN answer.  This started with you not even knowing if WPF ran on Citrix.